# Is this a valid/legal use of SE content?

Tags: support, legal

Googling for some information, http://www.unknownerror.org/opensource/ansible/ansible/q/stackoverflow/24162996/how-to-move-rename-a-file-using-an-ansible-task-on-a-remote-system came up as a result. The content appears to be an early version of the [SO question with the referenced ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24162996/how-to-move-rename-a-file-using-an-ansible-task-on-a-remote-system).

Attribution to SE is not explicitly stated, and at time of writing the page has a copyright notice for an entity sharing the name of the domain. Is this a correct usage of SE content?